Какую библиотеку я могу использовать для асинхронной работы с сессиями пользователя в Telethon?
Какую библиотеку я могу использовать для асинхронного сохранения сессий пользователя в Telethon? telethon-session-sqlalchemy не подходит, это синхронная библиотека.

Используй pyrogram
